# Examining memory in radare2 using registers

Tags: radare2

I can inspect `esp` in `radar2` using `dr esp`. In order to inspect `0x15(%esp)` I do the following:

```
    dr esp
0xff966c60
    ? 0xff966c60 + 0x15
0xff966c75
    px 4 @ 0xff966c75
```

Is there an easier way to do this? `px 4 @ esp + 0x15` is not what I need.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could chain your steps in a single command with something like `` px 4 @ `dr esp` + 4 ``, or simply use `px 8 @ esp` and look at the second word.